# SUMIF with CONCATENATE in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Previously, I had this formula, where F column is MeterID, F3 MeterID to find, and D column is Value.

```
=SUMIF($F$2:$F$337,$F3,D$2:D$337)/1000
```

It works great, but now I have to inclue a new column ConsoProd, that can have value "Conso", or "Prod"

Now I also want to sum, but have 2 differents sums for `MeterID, Conso` and `MeterID, Prod`

I don't know how to adapt formula.

Anybody can help me ?

Comment: use SUMIFS it will allow multiple criteria.

Comment: Thanks ! I tried : =SUMIFS(D$2:D$337, $F$2:$F$337,$F22, $C22)/1000 F22=MeterID and C22 = Conso, but I get an error :( . If I ommit the last condition ( C22), formula works, but it is equivalent to the previous formula

Comment: ah, ok, I think I know what went wrong, let me a minute

Comment: ok, I was forgetting the second range, now it works: =SUMIFS(D$2:D$337,$F$2:$F$337,$F22,$C$2:$C$337,$C22)/1000 -- You can put it as answer ! Thanks for your help